# PHP does not hide mysql_*() warnings, even if error_reporting(0) called

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I have an issue with `mysql_connect()`. I have done complex research, but found only some general articles about PHP error control operator or custom error handling in PHP and similar ones. My issue is like below:

I have [this code](https://github.com/Kubo2/diggyshelper/blob/v1.5-alpha2/web/connect.php#L22-31) and supposing to suppress `mysql_connect()`'s warning when the connection fails. When I was writing it, my thoughts were like this:

"Turn off errors, then connect to mysql server and if connection fails, suppress warning, then select the database and if selecting fails, suppress warning, and finally turn on errors."

But when I kill the MySQL service process, from PHP I get this warning:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): in C:\fakepath\connect.php on line 29
>
> Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\fakepath\connect.php on line 31

And that's not what the script I have supposed to do. Could you someone please explain me why does PHP do this?

I am aware that PHP's mysql extension is not recommended; but what I am working on is an older project and I know what I do.

Comment: You could try preceding those those particular lines with an @, suppressing the errors.

Comment: Sorry - not the lines, but the function calls, so:
$selectedDb = @mysql_select_db($dbData["name"], $connection);
etc.

Comment: Have you defined any custom `error_handler` which doesn't obey the error reporting level? That'd do it. Otherwise: a better option is to set `display_errors` to 0 instead of not reporting it: this way you'll still have you error logs but people won't see it.

Comment: You're going to get a ton more warnings in PHP 5.5+ because `mysql_query` is a deprecated interface. Hope you can upgrade this code before the function is removed from PHP.

Comment: @tadman Yes of course, I can.

Comment: @JacobEwing Thanks, but isn't `@` (internally) the same as I have yet in my code: `$level = error_reporting(0); trigger_error('silent notice', E_USER_NOTICE); error_reporting($level);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Posted on behalf of OP*:

Finally I have found an answer for this.

I had set `error_reporting` hardly via `php_admin_value` in my Apache's `httpd.conf` and according to that, any lower-level configuration (and also **script itself**) had been unable to override that setting.

I just commented out the directive and everything works as expected.